# Iframe is not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

http://stg.fanggle.com/analytics/pentaho/pendingtags.html in this link i have iframe ...

It is loading in chrome and in firefox it is showing error in console as:

1. Permission denied to access property 'mantle_initialized'
   http://bi.fanggle.com/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/reportviewer-app.js
   Line 65
2. Load timeout for modules: local!dojo 
   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
   http://bi.fanggle.com/pentaho/js/require.js
   Line 6

Can any one help me to solve this issue and display in all browser

Comment: Checked bug reports on it yet? Seems like there's a healthy bit of information provided by google on the subject of pentaho software

Comment: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-4067 FYI.